# WebView: libdispatch leaks in an ARC-enabled app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-leaks, webview

In a doc-based ARC-enabled application I have a WebView that is opening an HTML file. The idea is to do some editing, and then save to WebArchive. When I run Instruments I find random leaks as in the image below. I am not initializing anything with `malloc`, why am I getting them? (I get the leaks when I start opening and closing windows.)

**Document.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface KBDocument : NSPersistentDocument {
    IBOutlet WebView *webView;
}
```

**Document.m**

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

    NSString *urlStr = @"file:///Users/.........../Content/1/index.html";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:requestObj];
    [webView setEditable:YES];
}
```

**Leaks:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can see that the offending library is libdispatch; so it doesn't seems that your code is in error. 
Libdispatch http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/ is described here. You could check it out if you want to know more.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it out. I am new to cocoa, so the description doesn't make too much sense, it looks like it's for implimenting multi-tasking and using Grand Central Dispatch, rather than threads... I am not implementing anything like this in my code, so is it something I could safely ignore?

Comment: Probably. The frameworks you are using will be doing some things with threads and GCD, but you don't have to worry about them. If you ever find a large leak you should file a bug report.

Comment: Btw, when I comment out all the code, i still get the leaks, but when I deleted the webView from the interface builder, leaks stopped showing up!