# Memory Leak in iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, memory-leaks, instruments

I just create a simple `UITableView` in the `UIViewController`.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *_tableData;
    UITableView *_tableView;
}
@end
```

.m

```
#import "RootController.h"

@implementation RootController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        if (!_tableData) {
            _tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                [_tableData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_tableView release];
    [_tableData release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.view = view;
    [view release];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if (!_tableView) {
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        _tableView.dataSource = self;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableViewCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

I used instruments to detect memory leak for this, when I scrolled the `UITableView`, memory
 leak occurred.
[image]

I use Xcode 4.3.1 and iOS5.1 (iPod touch4).
Someone had this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the 'responsible library' column, you can see that the culprit is not your code. The leaks are small, you can safely ignore them.

Here is a similar question: [WebView: libdispatch leaks in an ARC-enabled app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612930/webview-libdispatch-leaks-in-an-arc-enabled-app)

Comment: @JesusRamos, If my program run several hours, it can be killed by the system because memory leak.

Comment: @looyao If it is interfering with normal app operation, report it as a bug.

Comment: @JoshRagem Link doesn't show similar question. It shows same question.

Comment: Correction now, WAS the same question :P

Comment: I also found the same question.http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/100313-memory-leak-tableview.html, so I think this is a bug.